# While or For loop in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How do I use a For loop in asp.net inside the  below? I have tried to use <% for(int i=0; i<5; i++)%> which gives me syntax error.
I am getting tired of the message "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:"

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="EmployeesListView" DataSourceID="EmployeesDataSource" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" OnDataBound="grd_RowDataBound">

  <LayoutTemplate>

    <table cellpadding="2" runat="server" id="tblEmployees" name="tblEmployees" style="width:100%" color="green">
    <tr id="Tr3" runat="server" style="background-color: red; color: yellow">  
        <th id="lbl1" style="display:none">Record No.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
    </table>

    <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager" PageSize="5">
      <Fields>
        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="5" PreviousPageText="<--" NextPageText="-->" />
      </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>

  </LayoutTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>

     <td valign="top" class="tdWithBorder" width="165" align="right" style="background-color: #D7E0EC; color: blue">
         <asp:Label ID="lblCallStatus" runat="server" Text='Call Status' />
         <br />

         <asp:Label ID="lblHoursWorked1" runat="server" Text='HoursWorked' />
            <br />

         <asp:Label ID="lblOTMealsPaid" runat="server" Text='Meals Paid'/>

         <br />
     </td>

    </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: We need more context. You've only posted an ItemTemplate without its parent container or the page itself.

Comment: Use code-behind and don't mix your logic with your markup.

Comment: David, I have updated the code...

Comment: IrishChieftain,  I have to do run a loop inside the <ItemTemplate> tag.  What I need is to write the following controls for a count of 30 (30 times).         <td valign="top" class="tdWithBorder" width="165" align="right" style="background-color: #D7E0EC; color: blue">
             <asp:Label ID="lblCallStatus" runat="server" Text='Call Status' />
             <br />

             <asp:Label ID="lblHoursWorked1" runat="server" Text='HoursWorked' />
                <br />

             <asp:Label ID="lblOTMealsPaid" runat="server" Text='Meals Paid'/>

             <br />
         </td>

Comment: If you're not binding to any DB data, why are you using a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code-behind here
http://everymanprogrammer.com/index.php/nested-repeaters-do-it-clean-and-simple-a-beginners-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: I do not want to do it in Code-behind; it needs t be done within the asp code I posted bove.